# Why is data not being exported to excel file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, export

I am working on an existing web application where the home page displays data in a tabular format. I am trying to export that data to a excel file but when even the row of the data table passes 607, I am unable to export the data into a excel file. All the data does show up in the home page perfectly but I can not export it.

The issue I am having is when the number of rows is more than 608 it opens a new tab on the browser and the link says `"about:blank#blocked"`

Here is the function that I am using:

```
function fnExcelReport() {
    var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var textRange; var j=0;
    tab = document.getElementById('bandwidthSummary'); // id of table
    
    for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++)
    {
        if(tab.rows[j].style.display == "none") {
            continue;
        }
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
        //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,""); // remove if u want images in your table
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus();
        sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Say Thanks to Summit.xls");
    }
    else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));

    return (sa);
}
```

Comment: What does "unable to" mean exactly? Do you get a Javascript error in the console, or something? BTW presumably you are aware that this code actually creates a HTML document, not an Excel file. Excel may be able to open such a file, but it's not actually a real xlsx or xls.

Comment: Yes. But the issue I am having is when the number of rows is more than 608 it opens a new tab on the browser and the link says "about:blank#blocked"